# NoMethodError: undefined method `const_defined?' when referring to class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building an email sending system into an already fairly complex rails app. 
From a controller I'm trying to call a method that builds an email and then delivers it.

In controller:

```
response_for :create, :update do
  estimate = current_object.estimate.reload
  flash[:success] = "Tier Save Successful. " 
  flash[:success] += send_estimate_email if estimate.verify && estimate.tiers.select{|t| !t.verified?}.empty?
  flash[:notice] = "This service bundle was changed for a previously verified service bundle.  Please re-verify after changes are complete" if current_object.auto_unverified
  redirect_to [current_object.estimate]
end

def send_estimate_email
    return "" if current_object.estimate.requestor_email.blank? || !current_object.estimate.requestor_notified_at.blank?
    begin
      estimate = current_object.estimate
      host = request.host_with_port
      binding.pry
      success = EstimateEmailer.deliver_verification_complete(estimate, host)
      current_object.estimate.notes.create!(:user_id => User.find(:first, :conditions => {:user_type_id => UserType::ROOT.id}).id, :title => "Verification Complete Email Sent", :body => "TO: #{success.to}\nSUBJECT: #{success.subject}\nBODY: #{success.body}")
    rescue Exception => e
      logger.warn(e)
      success = false
    end
    if success
      current_object.estimate.update_attribute(:requestor_notified_at, Time.now)
      current_object.estimate.notes.create!(:title => "Auto-email sent to requestor", :body => "TO: #{success.to}\nSUBJECT: #{success.subject}\nBODY: #{success.body}", :user_id => current_user.id)
      return "Automatic estimate email was successfully sent to #{current_object.estimate.requestor_email}"
    else
      return "However, automatic estimate email could not be sent due to an error"
    end
  end
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with the email code itself, but for some reason I get this error on the `EstimateEmailer.deliver_verification_complete(estimate, host)` call:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `const_defined?' for "estimate":String
```

setting a breakpoint in the controller before the EstimateEmailer call I notice that I get the error whenever I try to refer to other classes. Just calling `EstimateEmailer` or any other class name returns the same error.

I've run into issues with `undefined method const_defined?` in the past. I'm guessing the issue isn't specific to emailing, but I haven't the slightest idea where to begin debugging.

```
  def verification_complete(estimate, host)
    request_id = estimate.integration_transactions.empty? ? "Internal ID #{estimate.id}" : estimate.integration_transactions.last.source_id
    @estimate = estimate
    @estimate_url = public_estimate_url(estimate.public_id, :host => host, :protocol => 'https')
    mail(
      subject: "Ref ##{estimate.project_code} Application Hosting Estimate Available for Review: #{request_id}",
      to: [estimate.requestor_email, estimate.project_manager_email].reject{|email| email.blank? }.join(','),
      from: SUPPORT_ADDRESS
    )
  end
```

Comment: Show your exception backtrace.

Comment: This is literally all I get, would a full trace be in the logs or is there a flag I can set somewhere?

Comment: show `verification_complete` method code!

Comment: I'm fairly certain the `verification_complete` code doesn't matter as it never gets there. It seems to be a more fundamental issue not being able to even call other class names.

Comment: is that _all_ of the controller's action code? Are you sure that there is where the error happens? I suggest you add `puts` at strategic places in your code to find out where the exception actually occurs.

Comment: Share the method definition for current_object.estimate, or where you are getting that from

Comment: check your `Estimate` model for scopes named `parent` which is not allowed and could be causing this!

Comment: @UriAgassi Yes, that's all the code and yes the exception occurs on that call to `Estimate Emailer` but upon setting a breakpoint at that point in the code I've found that calling any other class name (e.g. `Estimate`) gives the same error. 
@Anand `current_object.estimate` is just accessing a member variable of an object that happens to be of class `Tier` there's not method behind it.
@Nimir I was thinking it was something like that, in the `Estimate` class there's a scope `scope :parents_for` but there is no parent scope anywhere in the project.

Comment: @markv12 - could you post the code _with_ the action declaration (`def my_action ... end`)?

Comment: @UriAgassi Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using make_resourceful which has an incompatibility with current versions of ActiveSupport. I've just lodged a PR that addresses it: https://github.com/hcatlin/make_resourceful/pull/16.

Alternatively, you can point to the remote branch in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'make_resourceful', github: 'carpodaster/make_resourceful', branch: 'fix/incompatibility-with-active-support-dependencies'
```

I assume this problem only occurs in your development environment, right? In that case, you should be able to avoid it by setting `config.eager_load = true` in `config/environments/development.rb`.